# Можно ли объявить класс перед его реализацией?

Tags: c++

Можно ли как-то объявить класс C, чтобы его могла увидеть функция fA?

```
class A {

        void fA (C object){};
    };

    class B {

        void fB (A object){};
    };


    class C: public B {
    };
```

Comment: Конечно да, просто пишете class C; строкой выше, чем объявление и реализация класса А

Comment: Можно, но надо будет передавать объект по ссылке или указателю, так как в случае forward declaration тип на момент разбора функции fA будет ещё incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

```
class C;

class A {

    void fA (C *object){};
};

class B {

    void fB (A object){};
};


class C: public B {
};
```